# Do Windows and Debian / Red Hat use the same thread management?

Tags: windows, debian, redhat-enterprise-linux, threads

I need to know what kind of thread management Windows and Debian / Red Hat use in  their recent versions.

I know that they used to use 1 to 1 thread management model. Do they still use this model to this day? Or did they change it?

Comment: entirely different models.

Comment: entirely different models is not an answer, I am researching and need an starting point, vague answers or implications are of no use.

Comment: Ramhound did not post an answer, but a comment. I'm not sure if this question isn't a little too broad. Are you looking for specific references? If so, please clarify what exactly you need to know.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. Operating systems don't really have thread management models.

Comment: @Hossein - Vague answers come from broad and overreaching questions.  Saying that Windows and Linux use two different thread management models is an acceptable response.

Comment: @slhck: I believe the question was indeed clear enough not get down voted or called too broad! the reason for that is i asked the same question in several places, and got the answers i was looking for. in none of those places i faced such behavior! which i guess is because of my low score in this section. I am well aware of the rules here after 3 years! so that doesnt count if you ask me .
Any way, Thank you very much for your concerns

Comment: Well, certainly you may believe that it's clear enough, but it's often a huge difference how a question looks to others who *might* know the answer but aren't quite sure about what exactly you mean. I wouldn't go as far as calling out users for their "behavior" here. I only see users asking for clarification. Of course I understand that you're upset about the downvotes. Note that we just have a very strong focus on questions that are about solving a specific problem, which obviously is not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From CProgramming Borad](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/tech-board/164855-what-thread-management-windows7-use.html#post1216449)

> The win32 API supports both the one-to-one and many-to-many models (in
>   the thread library and fiber library respectively).
>
> Windows 7, like all of the NT family, supports the win32 API.
>
> Windows 7 supports kernel threads. So it must be a one to one model or
>   many to many model. But it is in fact a hybrid that supports both
>   models. By default it will use traditional one to one scheduling, but
>   depending on the number of scheduling entities available to the OS
>   (based on the number of processors and cores), you can force it into a
>   many to many scheduler. The operating system itself will never shift
>   automatically. You must explicitly tell it to.
>
> Note that the 32bit version of Windows 7 does not support M:N
>   scheduling. Only the 64bit version.
>
> Linux can also support M:N through libraries like RIBS2, just as
>   windows would through the fiber API.
>
> Hybrid is always better because you have an option to optimize thread
>   scheduling, whereas before you had only one choice. But to take actual
>   advantage of a many to many scheduler is another matter altogether. It
>   will greatly depend on your need for a very large number of threads
>   and what they are actually doing. I don't know the exact details
>   though, since I was never involved in high performance projects with
>   the need to create a very large number of threads. It is my
>   understanding however that programming the threads becomes simpler,
>   but managing them becomes harder. In particular you spend a lot of
>   time in the testing phase trying to optimize your threads to the much
>   more complex scheduler.

[Toms Hardware:](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2356060/multithreading-methods-windows7.html)

> Prior to Windows 7, Windows used a one to one user thread to kernel
>   thread relationship. It was of course always possible to cobble
>   together a rough many to one user-scheduler (this can be done in
>   pretty much any OS with user-level timer interrupts) but if a system
>   call blocked on any one of the user threads it would block the kernel
>   thread and accordingly block all other user threads on the same
>   scheduler. Naturally, a many to one model cannot take advantage of
>   SMP.
>
> With Windows 7, Microsoft introduced support for user-mode scheduling.
>   A program may configure one or more kernel threads as a scheduler (one
>   per logical processor desired) and then create a user-mode thread pool
>   from which these UMS can draw. The kernel maintains a list of
>   outstanding system calls which allows the UMS to continue running
>   without blocking the kernel thread. This configuration can be used as
>   either many to one or many to many.